# "Invalid regular expression: unterminated group" when attempting to set up restify static route

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, restify

I am trying use restify to serve all paths that don't begin with `/api` from a directory containing static files.

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer();                                                                           
server.get(/^\/(?!api)/, restify.serveStatic({                                                                   
    directory: './static'                                                                                        
}));                                                                                                             

server.listen(8080, function() {                                                                                 
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);                                                
});
```

But, when I attempt going to, say, `http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html`, I get:

```
{"code":"InternalError","message":"Invalid regular expression: /^/(?!a/: Unterminated group"}
```

I am doubly confused because:

```
 $ node
> var e = /^\/(?!api)/;
undefined
> e.test('/api/v1');
false
> e.test('/index.html');
true
```

Comment: it's because u are using ?! which is basically checking for the negation of what you actually desire. `/^\/(api)/.test('/api/v1')` this should work for you I believe. And if it's just a test that u are performing the you don't even need those "()" round brackets a simple `/^\/api\//` should do.

Comment: @Sushil: I want the opposite of that.

Comment: The regex looks good, it will match `/foo` but not `/api/foo`

Comment: ah, ok I thought you wanted to filter the URL's containing `/api/`

Comment: That's right: as I wrote in my question, I want all paths not matching `/api` to be served from a static folder.

Comment: It looks like it might be misinterpreted ... `/^/(?!a/` in the error message is not the original `/^\/(?!api)/`

Comment: Yeah... what's with that? I've tried wrapping `RegExp`, and all that. I don't get it.

Comment: Do you get a stack trace? Since you are getting it when you request rather than when you start the server, it means `/^\/(?!api)/` is perfectly valid, as you have seen. There must be something in Restify that processes the regex that is breaking. Maybe it doesn't expect `?!`

Comment: I'm about to run this with `--debug` and pause on all exceptions to find out what it's doing. This has killed an hour of my life, "lol".

Comment: @mgamba: yeah, I saw http://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/741970 and tried that. no dice.

Comment: What's weird is that I also tried `/^\/[^a][^p][^i]/` and that's also messing up. I think something wrong in restify.

Comment: Wow... the offending restify code literally has this line: `route = route.substring(1, route.length-4);`. Just  trims off the last 4 chars of my regexp. ?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static files plugin was broken at the time of this posting. See my debug at https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/537.